# How to use regex (regular expressions) in Notepad++ to remove all HTML and JSON code that does not contain a specific string?

Tags: html, json, regex, notepad++

Using regular expressions (in Notepad++), I want to find all JSON sections that contain the string `foo`.  Note that the JSON just happens to be embedded within a limited set of HTML source code which is loaded into Notepad++.

I've written the following regex to accomplish this task:

`({[^}]*foo[^}]*})`

This works as expected in all the input that is possible.

I want to improve my workflow, so instead of just finding all such JSON sections, I want to write a regex to *remove* all the HTML & JSON that does *not* match this expression.  The result will be only JSON sections that contain `foo`.

I tried using the Notepad++ regex `Replace` functionality with this `find` expression:

`(?:({[^}]*?foo[^}]*?})|.)+`

and this `replace` expression:

`$1\n\n$2\n\n$3\n\n$4\n\n$5\n\n$6\n\n$7\n\n$8\n\n$9\n\n`

This successfully works for the last occurrence of `foo` within the JSON, but does not find the rest of the occurrences.

How can I improve my code to find all the occurrences?

Here is a simplified minimal example of input and desired output.  I hope I haven't simplified it too much for it to be useful:

***Simplified input:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <div dat="{example foo1}"> </div>
    <div dat="{example bar}"> </div>
    <div dat="{example foo2}"> </div>
  </html>
```

***Desired output:***

```
{example foo1}

{example foo2}
```

Comment: because of my poor understanding of English language ... I can better understand with sample text and it's Desired output...

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah Sure, no problem.  Let me create an example.

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah Thank you for your interest.  I just updated the question with sample text and it's desired output.  BTW, your English is likely better than you think! :)

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: @k-mx Yes, of course, but if you read the question carefully, you'll see the HTML is not being parsed.  Just think of the HTML as a long text string.

Comment: I suggest a three pass procedure. 1) bookmark all lines that contain the desired pattern. 2) Remove all unmarked lines. 3) Remove everything before `{` and after `}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```php
{[^}]*foo[^}]*}|((?s:.))
```

Replace with `(?1:$0\n)`. *Details*:

- `{[^}]*foo[^}]*}` - `{`, zero or more chars other than `}`, `foo`, zero or more chars other than `}` and then a `}`
- `|` - or
- `((?s:.))` - Capturing group 1: any one char (`(?s:...)` is an inline modifier group where `.` matches all chars including line break chars, same as if you enabled *`.` matches newline* option).

The `(?1:$0\n)` replacement pattern replaces with an empty string if Group 1 was matched, else the replacement is the match text + a newline.

See the demo and search and replace dialog settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Wiktor.  I had to shift priorities to another task, but I'm hoping to get back to the task involving this QA within several days.  I've upvoted your answer as it looks very helpful, and will respond back with questions/thanks once I have more time to take a closer look.

Comment: I'm sorry, not yet.  I haven't even had time to log in to SE/SO in almost a week.  I do have this on my list.  Feel free to ping again if you desire, I don't mind at all.

Answer (score 1):

Updates

The comment section was full tried to suggest a code here,
Let me know if this is a bit close to your intended result,

Find: `({.+?[\n]*foo[ \d]*})|.*?`
Replace all: `$1`

[image]
Also added Toto's example

Comment: This will not work if `{` and `foo` are not on same line.

Comment: @ Toto,  how for example?

Comment: `{ blah blah\nfoo }`

Comment: Then we will modify our codes to this  `^[\S\s]+?(.*\n*foo[ \d]*})|.`  but got no reply yet from OP

Comment: Thank you Haji.  I had to shift priorities to another task, but I'm hoping to get back to the task involving this QA within several days.  I've upvoted your answer as it looks very helpful, and will respond back with questions/thanks once I have more time to take a closer look.

Comment: @RockpaperLz you are welcome,  check my answer again and leave your comment, I just updated it,  with result in the image..